How to Set Up Scheduled Refresh for Power BI Reports on Power BI Server?
I'm new to using Power BI and recently started working with Power BI Server. I have created some reports and need to set up scheduled refreshes for them to ensure the data stays up-to-date. Could someone guide me through the steps to configure scheduled refreshes on the Power BI Server? Or this service only available to Power Bi Report Service?

What is Power BI Server? Do you mean Power BI Service (online powerbi.com)?
